# Is there any difference between creating indexes in Mongoose and creating indexes in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know that you can create indexes on fields using MongoDB and the same is possible using Mongoose as well. However, are there any differences between these?

For example, the indexes that Mongoose create, is it handled by Mongoose and not natively by the MongoDB? If yes, is there any performance or any other advantages or disadvantages against the same done natively in MongoDB?

OR does Mongoose internally just execute the MongoDB create index operations?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) they say :

[image]

---

In the sentence

> Mongoose automatically calls createIndex

It is clear that mongoose handle indexes using mongodb functions.